# How can I swap rows in CSV which contains millions of records in correct columns effectively?

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

How can I swap rows in CSV which contains millions of records in correct columns effectively? I want to swap some rows in the CSV file with correct order and column. The size of the file is too large which I can't do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to use some scripting language like **awk** to do it. 
Usually one-liner is enough to do such operation like swapping columns.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK